# dynamically rendered <h:inputText> with <a4j:ajax> not working

Tags: ajax, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have a section in page under   which is not rendered on page load.

On click of , I am showing that section. The section has  with  functionality. Once the section is rendered, the backing bean function is not invoked. Below is the code

```
<a4j:commandLink
    action="#{handlerBean.loadDetails}"
    render="iDetails"
>View/Edit
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Below is the sction which should be rendered on click of above commandLink.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="iDetails">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{handlerBean.showList}">
    <h:inputText
        id="newId"
        value="1234"
    >
       <a4j:ajax
           listener="#{handlerBean.someAction}"
       >
       </a4j:ajax>
   </h:inputText>
   </h:panelGroup>
```

someAction in backing bean is not getting invoked. Can someone please help in understanding if I am using  in a wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the `handlerBean.showList` change value? If it's not rendered then the listener wouldn't be processed.

Comment: The inputText is visible on click of the commandLink but without any ajax functionaity.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: On inspecting the element, I am seeing plain input tag as <input id="formId:newId" type="text" value="1234" name="formId:newId">